# User application gets killed when string is passed to kernel device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

We are developing an USB driver for our X86 Board and we are using Yocto as operating system. We are facing one mysterious issue and need your help, as we tried all our options.. We were able to find out which line the issue is..

This is the kernel driver code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    /* for put_user */
#include "test_strlen.h"

/*  
 *  Prototypes - this would normally go in a .h file
 */
int init_module(void);
void cleanup_module(void);
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static long test_ioctl(struct file *, unsigned int,
              unsigned long);

#define SUCCESS 0
#define DEVICE_NAME "test_strlen"   /* Dev name as it appears in /proc/devices   */
#define BUF_LEN 80      /* Max length of the message from the device */

/* 
 * Global variables are declared as static, so are global within the file. 
 */

static int Major;       /* Major number assigned to our device driver */
static int Device_Open = 0; /* Is device open?  
                 * Used to prevent multiple access to device */
static char msg[BUF_LEN];   /* The msg the device will give when asked */
static char *msg_Ptr;

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release,
    .unlocked_ioctl = test_ioctl 
};

static long test_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd,
        unsigned long arg)
{
    switch(cmd) {
        case IOCTL_CP210x_SET_SER_STR:
            {
                int retval = 0;
                unsigned char serial_str[127];
                memset(serial_str, 0x00, sizeof(serial_str));
                retval = copy_from_user(serial_str, (unsigned char *)arg,
                        strlen((unsigned char *)arg));
                printk(KERN_INFO"string from user: %s\n", serial_str);
                if (retval) {
                    printk(KERN_ERR"%s: failed to retrieve user argument %d\n",
                            __func__, retval);
                    return -EFAULT;
                }
                // retval = cp210x_set_serial_str(port, serial_str);
            }
            break;
            default:
                break;
    }

    return 0;
}
/*
 * This function is called when the module is loaded
 */
int init_module(void)
{
        Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);

    if (Major < 0) {
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Registering char device failed with %d\n", Major);
      return Major;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "I was assigned major number %d. To talk to\n", Major);
    printk(KERN_INFO "the driver, create a dev file with\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "'mknod /dev/%s c %d 0'.\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Try various minor numbers. Try to cat and echo to\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "the device file.\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Remove the device file and module when done.\n");

    return SUCCESS;
}

/*
 * This function is called when the module is unloaded
 */
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    /* 
     * Unregister the device 
     */
    unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
    // if (ret < 0)
        // printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in unregister_chrdev: %d\n", ret);
}

/*
 * Methods
 */

/* 
 * Called when a process tries to open the device file, like
 * "cat /dev/mycharfile"
 */
static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    static int counter = 0;

    if (Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;

    Device_Open++;
    sprintf(msg, "I already told you %d times Hello world!\n", counter++);
    msg_Ptr = msg;
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);

    return SUCCESS;
}

/* 
 * Called when a process closes the device file.
 */
static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    Device_Open--;      /* We're now ready for our next caller */

    /* 
     * Decrement the usage count, or else once you opened the file, you'll
     * never get get rid of the module. 
     */
    module_put(THIS_MODULE);

    return 0;
}

/* 
 * Called when a process, which already opened the dev file, attempts to
 * read from it.
 */
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp,   /* see include/linux/fs.h   */
               char *buffer,    /* buffer to fill with data */
               size_t length,   /* length of the buffer     */
               loff_t * offset)
{
    /*
     * Number of bytes actually written to the buffer 
     */
    int bytes_read = 0;

    /*
     * If we're at the end of the message, 
     * return 0 signifying end of file 
     */
    if (*msg_Ptr == 0)
        return 0;

    /* 
     * Actually put the data into the buffer 
     */
    while (length && *msg_Ptr) {

        /* 
         * The buffer is in the user data segment, not the kernel 
         * segment so "*" assignment won't work.  We have to use 
         * put_user which copies data from the kernel data segment to
         * the user data segment. 
         */
        put_user(*(msg_Ptr++), buffer++);

        length--;
        bytes_read++;
    }

    /* 
     * Most read functions return the number of bytes put into the buffer
     */
    return bytes_read;
}

/*  
 * Called when a process writes to dev file: echo "hi" > /dev/hello 
 */
static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Sorry, this operation isn't supported.\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

And the application code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h> // to get close() define
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test_strlen.h"

#define SER_STR "test"
#define PRODUCT_STR "CP2108 Quad USB to UART Bridge Controller"

int err_check(int ret, char* TAG);

int main()
{
    int fd, ret;
    unsigned char set_serial_str[256] = {};
    unsigned char get_serial_str[256] = {};
    unsigned char product_str[256] = {};


    fd = open("/dev/test_strlen", O_RDWR); 

    if (fd == -1) {
        printf( "Error opening port");
        return -99;
    }

    // Set serial string
    strcpy(set_serial_str, SER_STR) ;
    ret = ioctl(fd, IOCTL_CP210x_SET_SER_STR, set_serial_str);
    ret = err_check(ret, "SET_SER_STR");

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

int err_check(int ret, char* TAG)
{
    if (ret) {
        printf("FAILED - %s: ret = %d\t errno = %d\n", TAG, ret, errno);
        return -9999;
    }
    else {
        printf("SUCCESS - %s\n", TAG);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The code works fine when I run it on virtual machine.. But when i run the same on yocto image ( core-image-minimal intel-core-i7-x64 ), the application gets killed.

dmesg shows that it is failing when it is accessing the `strlen((unsigned char *)arg)`

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007ffef2503480
IP: test_ioctl.part.0+0x2d/0xdcc [test_strlen]
PGD 1790e1067 P4D 1790e1067 PUD 17708b067 PMD 179d8b067 PTE 8000000176ee5067
Oops: 0001 [#3] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
Modules linked in: test_strlen(PO) [last unloaded: test_strlen]
CPU: 1 PID: 13742 Comm: app Tainted: P      D    O    4.14.56-intel-pk-standard #1
Hardware name: NCR Corporation 7746-1410-8801/PX10, BIOS 4.0.5.0 01/17/2018
task: ffff9ca6b7beee40 task.stack: ffffaadb40138000
RIP: 0010:test_ioctl.part.0+0x2d/0xdcc [test_strlen]
RSP: 0018:ffffaadb4013bdd0 EFLAGS: 00010286
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9ca6b90cabd8 RCX: ffffffffffffffff
RDX: 00007ffef2503480 RSI: 00007ffef2503480 RDI: 00007ffef2503480
RBP: ffffaadb4013be60 R08: 0000003b9a5aed80 R09: 0000003b9a5aed80
R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffaadb4013bdd1
R13: ffff9ca6b903b500 R14: 0000000040018801 R15: 00007ffef2503480
FS:  00007fbecd6224c0(0000) GS:ffff9ca6bfc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 00007ffef2503480 CR3: 000000017a344000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Call Trace:
 test_ioctl+0x1c/0x20 [test_strlen]
 do_vfs_ioctl+0x99/0x5e0
 ? putname+0x4c/0x60
 SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
 do_syscall_64+0x65/0x120
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
RIP: 0033:0x3b9a2e98c7
RSP: 002b:00007ffef2503468 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000003b9a2e98c7
RDX: 00007ffef2503480 RSI: 0000000040018801 RDI: 0000000000000003
RBP: 00007ffef25037a0 R08: 0000003b9a5aed80 R09: 0000003b9a5aed80
R10: 0000000000000573 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 00000000004005e0
R13: 00007ffef2503880 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Code: 44 00 00 55 31 c0 48 89 fe b9 7f 00 00 00 48 89 e5 41 54 4c 8d a5 71 ff ff ff 53 4c 89 e7 48 83 c4 80 f3 aa 48 83 c9 ff 48 89 f7 <f2> ae 48 89 ca 48 f7 d2 48 8d 5a ff 48 83 fb 7f 48 89 da 77 0d
RIP: test_ioctl.part.0+0x2d/0xdcc [test_strlen] RSP: ffffaadb4013bdd0
CR2: 00007ffef2503480
---[ end trace ea1ff013117d3c15 ]---
```

Can you guys please help me why it is happening on yocto and not on VM..

Thanks for your help.. Much appreciated.

Comment: added dmesg output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
copy_from_user(serial_str, (unsigned char *)arg,
                    strlen((unsigned char *)arg));
```

`arg` is a user pointer, so it isn't safe to use `strlen()` on it. Use `strnlen_user()` instead. (And make sure that the length is capped at `sizeof(serial_str)`!)

This is probably succeeding on your VM because your processor and/or virtualization software don't support [SMAP](https://lwn.net/Articles/517475/), which detects and prevents this inappropriate access.

Comment: struct piclet_email_port_data
{
    unsigned int  num_bytes;
    unsigned char *data;
}__attribute__((packed));

retval = copy_to_user(((struct piclet_email_port_data *)arg)->data,
                                                email_port_data.data,
                                               (email_port_data.num_bytes));
This call is also failing.. Can't we write like this..